# Global tide data - is it out there?

Tags: data

I'm looking for a tidal range GIS layer. Anything global that shows either mean tidal range, maximum tidal range, or maximum tidal height. I have been trawling the web for tide related GIS layers and they don't seem to be available. If any one knows of a source, please let me know!

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10806/6229

Answer (score 2):

You could try out the [FES2014 Global Tide dataset](http://www.aviso.altimetry.fr/en/data/products/auxiliary-products/global-tide-fes/description-fes2014.html), which seems to be available for scientific use. It is a gridded dataset with a spatial resolution of 1/16 of a degree.

Comment: Hi Will, I did try this dataset, which is a great resource, but I am struggling to get a simple GIS layer out of it - it seems to be more for predicting tides at specific points/times. If you know how to extract a simple output of tidal range from this data, or know of someone who might, that would be really appreciated. Thanks for your help

Comment: I have not tried it. It looks like it comes as a NetCDF grid, which needs to be converted to a raster. If you are using ArcGIS, you could use Make NetCDF tool http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/netcdf/reading-netcdf-data-as-a-raster-layer.htm, otherwise there are GDAL options.